# FCM notification "click_action" not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using a Cloud Function and sending push notifications with it. Sending notification works as expected but click_action attribute not working. When I click the notification nothing happens. Here is my code:

**My notification payload:**

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
      title: 'Soru Çözüm',
      body: 'Attığınz soruya bir yorum geldi: ' + data.content,
      icon: 'ic_stat_logo',
      click_action: '.activities.SoruDetayActivity'
  },
  data: {
      title: 'Soru Çözüm',
      content: 'Sorunuz çözüldü.',
      post: data.parent
  }
};
```

**Intent Filter:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SoruDetayActivity"
    android:label="Soru"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name=".activities.SoruDetayActivity"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.website.com"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Your notification payload it seems correct.
Try to change your intent filter by removing the data and category.BROWSABLE tags like the below lines of code:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SoruDetayActivity"
    android:label="Soru"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name=".activities.SoruDetayActivity"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action name should be the **full name** of the activity to launch.  What you have now is the partial name, relative to the name of your app's package.  We can't see what that is here, since the prefix is elsewhere in your manifest.  Once you find it, it should look more like this:

```
  click_action: 'com.yourapp.activities.SoruDetayActivity'
```

Comment: Doug - did you actually try this? I'm having the same issue and supplying the full name didn't seem to help. From other posts it seems it should be enough that the string value here match the name= value in the manifest (but that isn't working for me either).

Answer (score 0):

`Notification` will try to launch the URL, the specified activity name does not qualify as URL, so Android won't perform anything as it doesn't recognise, instead if you use the `host` address mentioned in your `<data>` tag in `Manifest`, it should redirect you to that Activity, something like below

```
click_action: 'https://www.website.com'
```

Comment: Entering URL to 'click_action' attribute is not working either. Still nothing happens.

Comment: did you try using the actual data scheme ? I suppose `https://www.website.com` is an example

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is the Android Studio cache. Clear project and rebuild fix it. The string of android:name doesn't matter.
My Android Studio version is Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1